# How to run a remote task using user name and password when password contains a '€' character?

Tags: batch-file, command-line, fonts, jenkins, cmd

I'm trying to run a task on a remote server using Jenkins. I'm using this command line:

```
SCHTASKS /RUN /S <remote server> /U <user> /P <password> /TN <task name>
```

This always worked fine but now a new customer has a '€' character inside his password and I can't figure out how to pass it to my CMD line correctly. It's just being replaced by a '?' because the standard CMD font doesn't support th € sign.
Inside my CMD console I can solve the problem by changing the dafault font to "Lucida Console" but I can't do that in Jenkins or make a batch-script use that font.

Answer (score 0):

Most services/server which require authentication by user name and password do not allow characters with a code value greater decimal 127 because this results easily in problems like this one.

The [euro sign](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/20ac/index.htm) has the code value 20AC (hexadecimal, 8364 decimal) in Unicode table.

But in code page [Windows-1252](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252) for Western European and North American countries the [euro sign](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euro_sign) has code value 80 (hexadecimal, 128 decimal). In code page [Windows-1251](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1251) for Cyrillic text the euro sign has code value 88 (hexadecimal, 136 decimal).

So it must be found out what the service expects now for password:

1. A Unicode string or an "ANSI" string?
   (The Windows code pages as defined by Microsoft are not ANSI standard.)
2. Which code page respectively which code value to use in case of "ANSI" string.

The active code page on executing a batch file can be found out by running in a command prompt window the command `chcp` which can be used to switch the code page. See very short help output by entering `chcp /?`

The [code page 850](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1251) is for example set by default on German Windows for console.

Now let us assume the user has entered the euro sign in a GUI window which used Windows-1252 and the password string was encoded not in Unicode resulting in having stored the euro sign with decimal value 128. In this case it would be necessary to transmit a byte with value 128 in password string from within the batch file to service/server. By looking on the character table for code page 850 it can be found out that the character `Ç` has code value 128 in this code page. So try in your batch file the c-cedilla letter.

But best solution would be the user changes the password and avoids this time using a special character with a code value greater decimal 127.